# Pull MS Dynamics 365 CRM Data Values into Docusign Document

Tags: docusignapi

I'm trying to setup a Docusign document that will pull data values from the contact entity in MS Dynamics CRM.  For example, I want to populate the document with the contact Name, Address, Town, Postcode and Customer Number, but when I generate the document, the fields are blank.

I've created a custom button and process in Dynamics 365 that uses the Docusign intergration tools.  So far it will create the envolope correctly based on a template I have saved in DocuSign.  It is correctly specifying the recepient of the document and is bringing the correct email address into Docusign.
In the template I have a document that I have added a custom field to and have set the Data Label of the custom field - in the process I created in CRM i have used the "DocuSign.DSIntegrationActivity.MergeField" step to try and link the data value in the CRM contact entity with the Data Label of the custom field in DocuSign.  So far, when I run the process, when I preview the document, the custom field has either been removed, or has not populated with the data value from CRM.

Answer (score 0):

For this, please open a support ticket with us and we can help work through this with you specific to your use case.

https://support.docusign.com

Comment: Thanks Karman - i've tried to get logged into the Support page but it keeps telling me my login is invalid.  I have a DocuSign account but these details don't seem to work.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).